# wpf - Expand animation?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, animation, storyboard

I would like to replicate the [Android 6 Marshmallow open animation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k2eGVhoc8i0) in my WPF application on a Grid. So far, I've tried the obvious - animating the Scale property in Blend, but that stretches the contents, which I do not want. I want all the elements in my Grid to remain the "same stretch" as original. Animating the Width and Height properties wouldn't work because of them being Auto and I can't really use a fixed value.

How could I replicate that animation?

Answer (score 0):

I think margin should work. Start with a Margin ie. Margin(0, 0, window.ActualWidht() - 100, window.ActualHeight - 100) for starting in left top corner and stretch it to full window (going to Margin(0, 0, 0, 0)). replace window with control where you are using the animation. I'm not much familiar with animation but I hope this helps.

Comment: The problem with that is that it would cause all the elements inside the Grid to move as they adapt to the size of the Grid. I was thinking about having a rectangle that's Transparent or something, and scale that, so it would give the illusion of the other Grid expanding, but that obviously doesn't work.